# Simulate Geometric Brownian Motion with stochastic drift

Tags: plotting, simulation

I want to simulate a GBM with its drift parameter follows some continuous time Markov chain.

For example,

\begin{align}
dK & =\mu Kdt+\sigma K dW
\end{align}

where $\mu$ follows continuous-time Markov chain (CTMC) with transition rate matrix {{-1,1},{1,-1}}.

Unfortunately, I do not have a clue to start with. I understand `ContinuousMarkovProcess` can produce CTMC with integer-state between 1 and n like

```
P = ContinuousMarkovProcess[1, {{-1, 1},{1, -1}})]; 
data = RandomFunction[P, {0, 10}]*0.2+0.3;         
ListStepPlot[data]
```

[image: Simulation of CTMC]

Since the jump between 1 and 2 cannot fulfil my requirement, I do some linear transformation to the `data` in the example. It is also simple to simulation GBM in Mathematica just like

```
data2 = RandomFunction[GeometricBrownianMotionProcess[0.5, .1, 2], {0, 5, .01}];
ListLinePlot[data2]
```

[image: Simulation of GBM]

However, the question is the combination of these to simulate a mix of 2 GBMs in one curve and the drift is shifting between  0.5 and 0.7 follow the process in the first graph in the example.

Comment: Have you seen `ContinuousMarkovProcess`?

Comment: Welcome! I suggest the following:   
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)!   
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: What have you tried so far? If you can show code it is more likely that people can show a solution.